# Simple Menu Builder MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am relatively new in ASP.NET MVC 3. In the last couple of months I am working on simple portfolio site.
After hard work and learning MVC 3 I built site with backend for populating content of my site. Everything works fine and I am very impressed with framework.

My next step will be to upgrade my site to doing some basic CMS features. First I want to create backend page for creating simple controller with empty index action. I want to do that with simple web interface. Is there any blog post or simple code for such example.

Also I would like to know how can I create such feature and every hint will be welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's very hard to understand what do you need? You don't to dynamically create dinamic html page. Ok you can create dynamic controller and even register route for it but how would you make content for it?

Maybe you just need one controller what will redirects on html page depends on you rules from?

Comment: Thanks for respond. To be more clear I work with SharePoint CMS and I like to implement some features that are use on it like navigation. For example on sharepont i create new page and after that I go to administration and add new link on my navigation. 
Everything is done by web interface.

Now I want to create simple web interface that create me also new page (in case of asp.net mvc it is controller with action or new action in existing controller) and after that I want to create also web interface that allows me to add new item on site menu.

Comment: For example when I add new menu item it allows menu to add which controller ,action and name of menu item I want to display in menu using @Html.ActionLink() helper.

I know this is not simple work but I must start from some point and I don't know which is the best way to implement this.

Alex